# Dropdown menu SelctIndexChange not working as expected

Tags: c#, javascript, drop-down-menu, webforms

```
//master.cs     
protected void ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //alert box
            string message = "Some Content of the Site are only in English. Do you want to continue?";
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("return confirm('");
            sb.Append(message);
            sb.Append("');");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
       //alert end
            //Sets the cookie that is to be used by Global.asax
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CultureInfo");
            cookie.Value = ddlLanguage.SelectedValue;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            //Set the culture and reload the page for immediate effect. 
            //Future effects are handled by Global.asax
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ddlLanguage.SelectedValue);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ddlLanguage.SelectedValue);
            Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
    }

//master  Page
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" class="langpnl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="en-US">Eng</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="es-ES">Esp</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Whenever the user changes from English to Spanish I want to display an alert box. 
Its a weird behavior, this code is not working its not showing me any alert box on selected index change but if I paste the alert box code in the page load event it works. Is the pageload has to do anything with this?
Secondly is it possible to remember the answer i.e if the user selects an checkbox saying remember me, I should remember whether the user selected YES or NO throughout the session.
any suggestions on the second questions will help. But please help me find the reason why the above code is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code in your `dropdownSelected index changed event` to show the alert box

```
if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript"))
            {
                //give the exception details in a alert box
                string sb = string.Format(@"<script>alert('{0}');</script>'", "Message to be shown");
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSScript", sb);
            }
```

Comment: nothing it not showing any alert ...I have to use Page.ClientScript..If I only use ClientScript..it shows does not exsist in current context..

Comment: That code is working for me, did you get any error messages, and did you set `AutoPostback = true` for your dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

Register javascript event with `onchange="return CheckLanguage(this);"` instead of `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`.

**HTML**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" onchange="return CheckLanguage(this);" class="langpnl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="en-US">Eng</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="es-ES">Esp</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script Type="text/javascript>

function CheckLanguage(ddl)
{
    return confirm("Are you sure to change language");
}

</script>
```

Comment: Nope ..now the OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged" is also not working.

Comment: Did you get get javascript message? We might be missing something

Answer (score 1):

your event handler is not working as expected due to this ligne

```
Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
```

remove it if possible or try a work arround, and everything will be ok

**EDIT :**

To get by the issue caused by `Server.Transfer` try this and see if it makes sens

in your aspx file

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hide" />
```

in your code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (hide.Value == "true")
    {
        Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
    }
    hide.Value = "";
}   

protected void ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    sb.Append("if(confirm('")
     .Append(message)
     .Append("')){")
     .AppendFormat("document.getElementById('{0}').value = 'true'", hide.ClientID)
     .Append("}");

     ...

     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ddlLanguage.SelectedValue);
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ddlLanguage.SelectedValue);                
 }
```

Comment: I cannot remove it the pages behave inconsistently. only half of the controls changed to spanish..

Comment: Sorry to ask you another question...is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the user to a new page before they have a chance to confirm. `Server.Transfer` requests a new page (even though it's the same url) so your js never gets written to the page.  You need to run the confirm js before the postback ever happens.

I don't think you can prevent the `SelectedIndexChanged` postback either, as dot net adds it's own js event handlers to accomplish that. I think the least obtrusive method here to make a new button, move the language handler code to the button's click handler, then use client side js to click the button when the user confirms their choice.

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" class="langpnl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False">
        <asp:ListItem Value="en-US">Eng</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="es-ES">Esp</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="myHiddenButton" runat="server" Style="display: none;" OnClick="myHiddenButton_Click" />


void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string message = "Some Content of the Site are only in English. Do you want to continue?";
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("if confirm('");
        sb.Append(message);
        sb.Append("') ");
        sb.AppendFormat("document.getElementById('{0}').click();", this.myHiddenButton.ClientID);

        //Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());

        // write your js as the client-side onchange handler on the ddl
        this.ddlLanguage.Attributes["onchange"] = sb.ToString();

        //alert end
    }

    this.myHiddenButton.Click += new EventHandler(myHiddenButton_Click);
}

void myHiddenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // only ever called if user confirms the js prompt

    //Sets the cookie that is to be used by Global.asax
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CultureInfo");
    cookie.Value = ddlLanguage.SelectedValue;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    //Set the culture and reload the page for immediate effect. 
    //Future effects are handled by Global.asax
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ddlLanguage.SelectedValue);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ddlLanguage.SelectedValue);
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts ...is there any work around for the Server.Transfer(Request.Path);

Comment: myHiddenButton_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' is inaccessible due to its protection level....got stuck again

Comment: probably should be `protected void myHiddenButton_Click` i think. i did this on the fly. hook it up however you normally create an event handler for a button.

Comment: also you don't need a workaround for `Server.Transfer`, you just can't do it before the user confirms their choice.

Comment: I don't know whats wrong but there  are no more errors and still no alert box...:( I think for now I'll go to old school method Response.Write("<script>confirm('All content may not be in Spanish. Do you want to continue...');</script>");